# Change automatically the format of date fields (Laravel)

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, date, mutators

I'm looking for a DateTime Mutator that change the format of dates, **I'm working with Oracle DB** and the admitted Format is (DD/MM/YYYY) and the input type "date" stores dates in (YYYY,MM,DD) format.

I found the $date function and a trait by Torzer, but I have to indicate the fields that I want to convert the format.

is there some trait or function that detect all date fields and convert them automatically in a format (DD/MM/YYYY)? this without indicate the field.

nowadays I use protected $date in my model:

```
protected $dates = [ 'fecha_nac', 'fecha_nac1', 'fecha_nac2', ];
```

Comment: What's wrong with specifically defining the date fields on the model yourself?

Answer (score 1):

By default laravel uses date formate 'Y-m-d H:i:s' if you want to use a different format you can customize it in your model in the following way.

```
    protected $dateFormat = 'your date formate';
```

in your case it will be.

```
    protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `getDates` method on `HasAttributes` trait.

```
/**
 * Get the attributes that should be converted to dates.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getDates()
{
    $defaults = [static::CREATED_AT, static::UPDATED_AT];

    return $this->usesTimestamps()
                ? array_unique(array_merge($this->dates, $defaults))
                : $this->dates;
}
```

On your model:

```
public function getDates()
{
    $dates = parent::getDates();

    // add your dynamic logic here

    return $dates;
}
```

I would really go for explicitly defining which fields should be converted as these dynamic operations can be expensive if you are working with the model quite a lot.

Comment: Hi, but what if I have 10 models with 10 different date fields? and not two static fields. I would need to make the function for each date field?

Comment: You will either have statically defined which fields are dates on each model (which is pretty clean) using `$dates` property, or you can have some custom logic (lets say the date field is prefixed with `d_`) and override the `getDates` method to search for this pattern and add the field to `$dates` array dynamically.

You can declare these properties/methods on the model without using trait btw.